# Question about how to trigger Projections

Tags: events, microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm learning CQRS and common tactical DDD patterns and I'm kind of confused about how to trigger projections that's in another microservice.

For learning purposes, I'm not using Event Sourcing right now, and read models are stored in a PostgreSQL database.

So coming to the question, when a command is executed, the aggregate is updated and stored to a PostgreSQL Database. My question is how will I let the projections that on a different microservice know when to trigger the projection and update the read models?

I have a few questions on what to propogate, and as what form and through which channel to propogate this:

1. Regarding what to propogate - I'm under the assumption that Event Sourcing events used for persistence are different from the Domain Events and Integration Events used for loose coupling. So people usually send the granular Event Sourcing events that they persisted to the Event Store (Like ProductNameChangedEvent or ProductShipmentReceivedEvent) to update the projections. Since I'm not using Event Sourcing, should I be sending the model that I persisted, and using that to trigger a projection, like a ProductUpdatedEvent? Or should I be sending granular events too?
2. Regarding the form and channel of propogation -Should I be sending these events in the form of IntegrationEvents? I'm asking this cuz I'm confused on whether IntegrationEvents should only be used for Business based events for other services instead of events just to update database.
   Sorry if I sound stupid at certain points, kindly let me know if I made mistakes on concepts outside the question too.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm asking this cuz I'm confused

1. That's not your fault.
2. The literature sucks.

---

> when a command is executed, the aggregate is updated and stored to a PostgreSQL Database. My question is how will I let the projections that on a different microservice know when to trigger the projection and update the read models?

The common answer is to design your protocols such that the consumers poll the provider for changes/udpates.  After all, you would have to fall back to that anyway in the event that the consumer is down for maintenance when the provider is announcing an update.

Your polling interval(s) are determined by the client's ability to meet its own service level objectives (frequent polling when having fresh information is critical, not so much when the costs of stale information are low).

For those cases where some unusually urgent change needs to be shared, provider pushes a notification to consumer - essentially a message saying "you should probably poll as soon as possible".

> I'm under the assumption that Event Sourcing events used for persistence are different from the Domain Events and Integration Events used for loose coupling.

Yes, but don't get too tangled in the semantics.  Information moves from here to there via *messages*.  Producer and consumer need to have common understanding of the semantics of the messages if the information is to be properly understood, and you need to have some care about designing your messages in such a way that you can evolve them to meet future needs.

When coordinating changes between producer and consumer is *expensive*, then you need to invest in designing your message schemas such that changes to the schemas don't require coordinated change (aka forwards/backwards compatibility).

Kicker: your persisted representations of information are "just" messages from past you to future you.  What makes them special is that coordinating changes between producer and consumer are cheap when producer and consumer are the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "After all, you would have to fall back to that anyway in the event that the consumer is down for maintenance when the provider is announcing an update" ? This is a disaster recovery procedure and you can plan it with many tools (persistent logs in Kafka or outbox pattern). Polling is not recommended as it leaves a heavy burden on the producer to fetch everything just to be sure it's all updated.

Answer (score 1):

Integration events are for integrating multiple bounded contexts, not for integrating write and read data stores. But you are not wrong. If you are not using Event-Sourcing, you should use messaging to integrate these two data stores.

Martin Fowler, in his [EagerReadDerivation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/EagerReadDerivation.html)  article says much about it. He says that the result of domain actions can be published in a queue. The read model processes the queue messages and updates itself.

> should I be sending the model that I persisted, and using that to
> trigger a projection, like a ProductUpdatedEvent? Or should I be
> sending granular events too?

In the message processing, you don't need to check invariants. As the messages are the result of a valid domain action. So, I think you can put the last state of your record in the message. It's not necessarily right or wrong. But you should consider these situations:

- **Messages Order**: If you choose to put the last state, you have to process the messages one by one and in order.
- **Idempotency**: If you choose to put the event data in the message, you should implement idempotency, as processing the same event should not affect the resulting object.

**Edit:**
There is another option that you can pull the last state of data from the write model in processing the read model messages. In this case, you don't need to worry about idempotency and ordering but at the cost of hitting write model data store more frequently.

Comment: So I shouldn't be thinking of these events as IntegrationEvents right? Should I think of them as a separate group of messages just for updating reading stores?

Comment: Since these read model updating messages are not notifying domain concepts like OrderPlaced etc., should I still be raising them from Domain Event Handlers, which is not making sense to me right now? Or should I be publishing them from my Repositories every time an aggregate is saved or deleted etc.

Comment: There are some concerns here. First, how to be sure that these messages are going to be sent transactionally with the actual changes? We should use the Outbox pattern. Second, who has the knowledge of the message? I think the domain has it. Not the repository nor the ApplicationLayer. Domain knows when, what, and the data to notify other services via messages. But it doesn't know how to notify. This responsibility lies in the infrastructure layer.